# How do I put back 3G data connection

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, data-connection

Maybe a month ago I set my device to use only wifi for data connection. Now, with a bigger data package, I try to find where I can put back 3G for data connection.

I didn't do any fancy tricks nor # 4036# ... things.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn 3G data back on through 'Settings'.

1. Go to 'Settings'
2. Go to 'Wireless & Networks'
3. Somewhere near the bottom should be 'Mobile Network' - enable it

Now you're phone should have both 3G and WiFi enabled. If it can connect to a WiFi, it'll use WiFi; otherwise, it'll fall back to use 3G.

edit: as Seth pointed out below, these instructions may differ slightly between android phones (but should be relatively similar). Instructions above are for the HTC Desire.

Comment: The option on his phone should list, Use Packet Data

Comment: Thank you. I had to turn off and on the device for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Samsung Nexus S.
I think most of the android phones are very similar.
Please follow the following steps;

1. Go to "Settings";
2. Go to "Wireless & Networks"
3. Scroll down to the bottom, go to "Mobile network settings".

Now you could enable "Data enabled" option, which is the first option could be selected.

Then, you could access the network through wifi or 3G.

Good luck.